# Nessus port scanning crashes AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to do a port scan on AWS instance using Nessus software . Once I start scanning the instance getting Crashed , throwing an exception unresponsive ports.

Could any one please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a normal scan which was working before. Even now it works fine in new AMI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under no circumstances should you either use an AWS instance to run port scans, or port scan an AWS instance without obtaining permission first. Submit a support ticket. It is very likely that Amazon are simply shutting down your unauthorised activity with their security mechanisms. This is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** have a nessus scanner in the VPC where your client lives. Then, your Security Center needs to be configured to talk to the nessus scanner. Then, your VPCs nessus scanner with scan the AWS instance.
Otherwise, AWS see's this as an attack and "bad things" happen.

And, do what @monkeymatrix said.